# Basic auth using squid proxy

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, squid

I'm trying to make Squid3 to use basic authentication.  I'm setting this up on ubuntu14.04 on EC2

I started by following http://hackingonstuff.net/post/23929749838/setting-up-a-squid-proxy-on-aws and have manged to get it working without auth.

Now I'm trying to follow http://soad1982.blogspot.com/2013/05/squid-proxy-on-aws.html to set up the basic auth

my `squid.conf` CONTAINS:

```
acl all src all
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow all
http_port 3128
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3    


auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off
acl foo proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access deny !foo
http_access allow foo
http_access deny all
```

I'm trying to create `/etc/squid3/passwd` with:

sudo htpasswd -c /etc/squid3/passwd myusername

This seems to work ok. I restarted using:

```
sudo restart squid3
```

When I set my browser to surf through the proxy, I get the right ip address according to http://www.whatsmyip.org/ but I'm not prompted for the password or username.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a long time since I configured a squid but as far as I remember the directive `http_access allow all` in line 4 of your configuration makes the 3 lines at the very bottom obsolete… You might try to remove that one.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Knut, I've been looking at http://wiki.squid-cache.org but its confusing. Do the first directives trump the later directives? I am putting mine at the end assuming that the last directives trump anything earlier

Comment: Just looked it up: The first matching rule is it…

"For each request that Squid receives it will look through all the http_access statements in order until it finds a line that matches. It then either accepts or denys depending on your setting. The remaining rules are ignored." [Source](https://workaround.org/squid-acls)

Comment: btw , would you mind checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765937/configure-chrome-browser-to-use-proxy-server

Comment: As you said I removed "http_access allow all" and it started working. Many thanks -Bill