# Configure chrome browser to use proxy server

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I'm trying to make Squid3 to use basic authentication.  I'm setting this up on ubuntu14.04 on EC2

I'm following http://hackingonstuff.net/post/23929749838/setting-up-a-squid-proxy-on-aws and have managed to get through steps 1-3:

for step 4 I have done:

[image]

Step 5 says:

```
Depending on your OS/browser, you should configure the system to access the Internet
via the proxy for both HTTP and HTTPS (e.g. ec1-11-11-11-11.compute-2.amazonaws.com:3128).
```

I have opened up the chrome settings browser and configured the proxy as

[image]

unfortunately when I open , http://www.whatsmyip.org/ the connection times out. What am I doing wrong?

addendum:

after entering netstat -tulpen at the command line I got:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode
   PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8476
   -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          8478
   -
tcp6       0      0 :::3128                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          8685
   -
```

So I'm assuming its functioning OK..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration you posted above looks good to me. Are you sure the Squid is running and accepting connections on port 3128? At least I don't find any mistake in the screenshots…

Comment: Try `netstat -tulpen` and look for the squid listening on `0.0.0.0:3128`. (If its listening on `127.0.0.1` you need to modify your configuration to get it listen on `0.0.0.0`. If its not running start it…)

Comment: It's listening only on tcp6 ports not on tcp4 ports… Too bad AWS currently does not support IPv6… You can fix that by following [this article](http://www.barlow.eu.com/techblog/squid-3-listening-ipv6/).

Comment: Awesome! I was able to fix it using the article and restarting squid. I'm now getting: " Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time." so I can see that my config file needs some work. I would never been able to figure that out without your help - best regards - Bill